# stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString not work as expected when pinyin replace ǘ to v

Tags: ios, nsstring, chinese-locale

I try to convert pinyin ǘ to v after

```
CFStringTransform((__bridge CFMutableStringRef) mutableString, NULL, kCFStringTransformToLatin, false);
```

but when

```
(lldb) po [@"uán" stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"ǘ" withString:@"v"]
```

the output is:

```
vn
```

uá eat disappear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the below code, Why I thought this might work? I got some hint from [How Swift String saves the unicode chars](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html)

I still don't know how this worked, may be I need to read more about Obj-C strings especially how it saves the unicode chars

```
NSString *text = @"uán";
NSString *repStr = [text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"ǘ" withString:@"v" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, text.length)];
NSLog(@"%@", repStr);
```

Console logs

> TestObjc[1221:69730] uán